# auth/google_oauth2 not working on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, rubygems, google-oauth

I was able to make an authentication using Facebook and wanted to try Google for my rails app but after installing the gem omniauth-google-oauth2 and giving the proper code to the omniauth.rb I can´t make it work to the url /auth/google_oauth2

Here is my code:

```
    OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

    Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
     provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
     :scope => 'email', :display => 'popup'
     provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], 
     {
         :name => "google",
         :scope => "email, profile, plus.me, http://gdata.youtube.com",
         :prompt => "select_account",
         :image_aspect_ratio => "square",
         :image_size => 50
     }


end
```

After i run the `bundle install`command and try to go to /auth/google_oauth2 I get the error `No route matches [GET] "/auth/google_oauth2"`.
I followed the instructions of the gem and also I did not need to set a route for the /auth/facebook method.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you restart the server after making all the changes?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server, re installed the gem and nothing. It's still in development. I haven't tried in production.

Comment: Are you using Devise by any chance?

Comment: No, I was thinking to do it but I followed the instructions in [This railcasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication)  to make the Facebook authenitaction and tried to do almost the same thing with Google authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Try directing to:

/auth/google

Comment: Yes, in your example it needs to be `/auth/google`, since you've set the `name` option to `google` in your config file.